# Failed to install *.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No space left on device

Tags: android, emulation

I've seen the questions posted about this issue. I understand it takes several minutes for the emulator to configure itself and launch. But if I'm getting the specific error:
[I recently deploy the project to emulator finding this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOWzH.jpg)

At the same time,I use genymotion simulator,but I don't find it on DDMS
[thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs5W1.jpg)
thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Edit the emulator settings and give it more internal space.